# Using the advanced filter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 40 rows in Excel starting with a SerialID in sheet 1. In sheet 2 i have 109 rows which I would like to filter based on sheet 1. Sheet 1 contains records i want to hide from sheet 2.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400850/apply-filter-from-a-master-worksheet-to-multiple-worksheets

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `SerialID`s are in ColumnA of each sheet, add a column in `sheet 2` with a formula of the kind `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)` (adjust `A2` as required) and copy down. This should find those that exist in `sheet 1` so filter to select those that don't (ie tick `#N/A` only).